# Form resubmission error in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have a visual force component that displays records of a custom object named customer. After I create a new record of customer object, I start getting form resubmission warning before every refresh. The warning goes away only if I close and reopen the contact. Due to this warning, the record I delete gets undeleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Form Resubmission Bug**

The issue was that code was generating HTTP POST request instead of HTTP GET request. This resulted in view state getting saved and hence the form resubmission warning. This also resulted in undelete of a deleted record.
To solve this issue, we made changes in save method of controller. The return type of the method was page reference and it’s job was to save a record and refresh the page.

**SetRedirect(boolean) property**

If true, the page will send HTTP GET request
If false, the page will send HTTP POST request
The default value of this function parameter is true. Except when the page reference redirects to the same page, it’s default value is false.
In code, before returning the page reference, we have to make this property as true. If not, HTTP POST request will be sent and you will receive a form resubmission error.

```java
        //return null;      //This results in form resubmission error. It generates a HTTP POST response and stores state of page. In this case it results in undelete of a record after it is deleted and page is refreshed. In some cases, it may also result in duplicate record creation.
                            //As we are redirecting to the same page, setRedirect() property of page reference is set to false. This generates a POST request. We need to make it true so as to generate a GET request. GET request does not store the state of the page and the form resubmission warning disappears.

        //instead, use this code
        PageReference tempPage = ApexPages.currentPage();   //Create page reference to the same page          
        tempPage.setRedirect(true);     //Set the redirect property to true
        return tempPage;    //Return the page reference to refresh the page
```